# Is there a way to add a Null option to webform radio buttons?

Tags: webform-civicrm

When using a Drupal Webform with CiviCRM it is possible to add a Null or 'Empty' option to a Select input box, if using a dropdown list.  Is there a way to do the same thing if using radio buttons?

Comment: D7 or D8 as it may matter

Comment: If the field is not marked as Required then it can be left empty.  Does that do what you need?

Answer (score 1):

No Required Radios example:

[image]

Alternatively in CiviCRM -> Custom Fields -> If you wanted to specifically record the 'none' option simply add it as an Option (Add Option) and it will automatically appear on your webform as an option as well!

[image]

Comment: Null seems to be following you lately @karing-semper-it ...

Comment: :-) :-) I know...

Comment: This is on D7. 

I'm dealing with the field which selects Membership Types, where it defaults to the existing value if a Membership already exists, and I wanted an option for the user to turn it off.  Required doesn't affect that, and adding an 'Empty' type isn't really what's wanted.

I can add a separate button and uncheck it with JavaScript, but the server still  defaults  to the previous value unless there is an explicit alternative set.  I guess I could try adding another radio with JS which returns a value the server doesn't understand, maybe try that later.

Comment: it may help if you explain your scenario more thoroughly in your Question. eg scenario is a webform that allows for membership renewal but does not require it and the need is to prevent civi default behaviour of expecting someone to renew an existing membership

Comment: the answer to which may be, add a field that says 'do you want to renew, add a membership or not', and then use Conditionals to set the Membership value (if that works. not tested)